# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar un botón hasta que un formulario esté lleno? angular 9 TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

lo que quiero es que un botón que esté des-habilitado se habilite cuando el usuario llene un pequeño formulario.
Estoy usando angular 9.
Vi varias respuestas pero están en JavaScript y yo estoy en TypeScript

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterPost" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="searchTextNombre">
<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterPostt" placeholder="Edad" [(ngModel)]="searchTextEdad">
<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterPostt" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="searchTextEmail">
<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterPostt" placeholder="fecha" [(ngModel)]="searchTextFecha">
<br>
<button (click)="getconsultas()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> continuar
</button>
```

Comment: Puedes compartir algo de tu codigo?estas usando formularios por template o reactivos?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `formControls` de angular para validarlo, te pongo un ejemplo.
Es necesario importar `FormsModule` y `ReactiveFormsModule` en `app.module` para tener disponibles las funciones necesarias.
Primero en tu TS es necesario crear los `formControls` de tus inputs o elementos con sus correspondientes validadores para hacer requerido el input y posteriormente creas un `formGroup` con estos `formControls` para que funcione en la etiqueta `form` y puedas validar un formulario completo.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  public name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  public lastName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

  public newForm = new FormGroup({
    name: this.name,
    lastName: this.lastName,
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public onSubmit(){
  }

}
```

Despues en tu html agregas un form y los inputs o elementos que necesites y al final el boton con la propiedad `disabled` bindeada el validador del `formGroup` hará la magia para que el botón se actualice conforme la configuración, ya que los validadores ademas de solo validar que exista algo en el input, se pueden validar tipos de datos como string, number, estructuras como email y hasta longitud de caracteres.

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="newForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    </label>
    <label>
      Last Name:
      <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
    </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!newForm.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

De la manera que lo estas haciendo debes de acceder a los errores de esta manera:

```
<input 
type="text" 
class="form-control" 
name="filterPostt" 
placeholder="Email" 
//Esta es una referencia al input
#searchTextEmailTempl="ngModel"
[(ngModel)]="searchTextEmail"
// Validaciones propias del html
required
>
//Aqui agregas tu mensaje de validacion. 
<div *ngIf="searchTextEmailTempl.errors.required">searchTextEmail is required</div>
```

Para validar los inputs necesitas revisar cada uno. Puedes pasarlos en un arreglo.

```
<button (click)="getconsultas([searchTextEmailTempl])"> Ejecutar </button>
```

Y en tu componente:

```
getConsultar(campos:any [] ){

   let invalido = campos.find(campo=> campo.errors.length>0)

   if( invalido ) {
       console.log('Hay campos invalidos')
       return 

    }

//... mas logica
}
```

> El codigo esta echo sobre la marcha y puede contener errores.